# How to select similar(same or close) values from one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am sorry, probably my question sounds strange, I do not formulate it more understandable. I will try to explain it below.

I have a `df` with two columns: `age` and `disease`. The column `age` includes different people from 25 years old to 75 years old. The column `disease` has binary output (0- healthy; 1- sick).

the example:

`d = {'age': [25,34,45,67,67,44,55,67,26], 'disease': [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]}`

`df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`

This data frame is tiny compared with mine.

I need to create a new df1 with a similar distribution of age for two groups. It means that if I take, for example, sick people from `df` with age == 25 and age==45, I need to take with same if it is possible or close age from healthy group (in my `df` 26 years old and 44).

But imagine, the number of healthy people is bigger than sick, and I need to do this process with 100 iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# first of all create two separate dataframes of sick and healthy.
sick = df[df['disease']==1]
healthy = df[df['disease']==0]

# get sick ages to numpy
sick_ages = sick['age'].to_numpy()

# filter healthy dataframe with +- 1 year or exactly the same age
near_sick = healthy[(healthy['age'].isin(sick_ages-1)) | (healthy['age'].isin(sick_ages+1)) | (healthy['age'].isin(sick_ages))]

   age  disease
5   44        0
8   26        0
```

Comment: Thank you, but near_sick contains 0 in column 'disease' (it means healthy) and number of rows is equal to healthy df, not to sick

Comment: "I need to take with same if it is possible or close age from healthy group". It's returning close age from healthy group as you requested